# Find the number in list which is not present in Database column

Tags: java, oracle

I have one requirement where I need to find the first missing number in the ArrayList which is not there in Database(Oracle) column.

Scenario is like this :

Table 1:

[image]

From the above table I am thinking to make 3 lists

```
List<Integer> lst1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> lst2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> lst3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

lst1 -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6....1000]

lst2 -> [a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6....a1000]

lst3 -> [b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6....b1000]

As of now the lists contains approx 1000 values in the serial order.

Now I have a Database table as below

[image]

How can I match the lsts with Range column.
I need to find what value from lsts is not present in this table ?

Like in this case, if we see from the "lst1" the first available value which is not there in the table is "1" then next available value is "3" and then 5.6...so on.
Similarly for "lst2" the first missing value is "a3"

Is there any way to do ?

Comment: I would much rather join a table containing your serial integers than do the work in Java.  Is there any chance of getting this data into a table?

Comment: Apart form above solution, if the table is small then run the query `select distinct range from tab` and cleanup your list from from the data that you received from DB.

Comment: If this is only going to be done once and/or you are not really concerned about performance or elegance, then a brute force method of loop through `lst` and querying the DB would work.  If the Database table is not  large then 1000 queries may be the simple answer

Comment: @Everyone : I just modified my question to include the exact scenario. Just to clarify 2nd table would be having millions of records.

Comment: write the list to a temp table, and do a "not in (select ..whatever.. from temp table).

Comment: @NitinKalra *2nd table would be having millions of records*  If this is indexed properly it may not make any difference.  More importantly is how this is going to be used and whether the data is static or not

Comment: Scary Wombat:. the request will come every second and list will be iterated which will put lot of search queries on second table.

Answer (score 1):

The below query obtains a prefix and numeric valuest of range_start and range_end.
For simplicity of examples I limited ranges to 0-5

```
SELECT  lstname,
        regexp_substr( rangestart, '[^0-9]') AS Prefix,
        regexp_substr( rangestart, '[0-9]') AS r_start,
        regexp_substr( rangeend, '[0-9]') AS r_end
FROM table_1

LSTNAME |PREFIX |R_START |R_END |
--------|-------|--------|------|
Lst1    |       |0       |5     |
Lst2    |a      |0       |5     |
Lst3    |b      |0       |5     |
```

The below query will generate all values for ranges using the above query as a subquery.
Please note that `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` works on version Oracle 12c and later, if you are using earlier version then this query must be rewriten.

```
SELECT lstname, prefix || val AS val
FROM (
        SELECT  lstname,
                regexp_substr( rangestart, '[^0-9]') AS Prefix,
                regexp_substr( rangestart, '[0-9]') AS r_start,
                regexp_substr( rangeend, '[0-9]') AS r_end
        FROM table_1
) x
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT LEVEL - 1 + x.r_start AS val
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= x.r_end - x.r_start + 1
)

LSTNAME |VAL |
--------|----|
Lst1    |0   |
Lst1    |1   |
Lst1    |2   |
Lst1    |3   |
Lst1    |4   |
Lst1    |5   |
Lst2    |a0  |
Lst2    |a1  |
Lst2    |a2  |
Lst2    |a3  |
Lst2    |a4  |
Lst2    |a5  |
Lst3    |b0  |
Lst3    |b1  |
Lst3    |b2  |
Lst3    |b3  |
Lst3    |b4  |
Lst3    |b5  |
```

And now say that `table_2` contains the following values:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2

RANGE |
------|
3     |
a0    |
a1    |
a5    |
b3    |
b4    |
b5    |
```

To find missing values just LEFT JOIN the above queries to this table and filter out not null values.
Please note that I am using `"RANGE"` within quotes as a column name in this example because `RANGE` is reserved word in Oracle

```
SELECT lstname, val
FROM (
        SELECT lstname, prefix || val AS val
        FROM (
                SELECT  lstname,
                        regexp_substr( rangestart, '[^0-9]') AS Prefix,
                        regexp_substr( rangestart, '[0-9]') AS r_start,
                        regexp_substr( rangeend, '[0-9]') AS r_end
                FROM table_1
        ) x
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT LEVEL - 1 + x.r_start AS val
           FROM dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= x.r_end - x.r_start + 1
        )
) XX
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
ON t2."RANGE" = xx.val
WHERE t2."RANGE" IS NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2;

LSTNAME |VAL |
--------|----|
Lst1    |0   |
Lst1    |1   |
Lst1    |2   |
Lst1    |4   |
Lst1    |5   |
Lst2    |a2  |
Lst2    |a3  |
Lst2    |a4  |
Lst3    |b0  |
Lst3    |b1  |
Lst3    |b2  |
```

---

This version of subquery emulates a lateral join and should work on Oracle 10, but I've not tested it

```
SELECT lstname, 
   prefix || column_value AS val
FROM (
        SELECT  lstname,
                regexp_substr( rangestart, '[^0-9]') AS Prefix,
                regexp_substr( rangestart, '[0-9]') AS r_start,
                regexp_substr( rangeend, '[0-9]') AS r_end
        FROM table_1
) x
CROSS JOIN  table(cast(multiset(
   SELECT LEVEL - 1 + x.r_start AS val
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= x.r_end - x.r_start + 1
) as sys.OdciNumberList)) q
;
```

Comment: Thanks, Whats the other way to write the query without cross later join ? Because I am working on Oracle 10 instead of 12.

Comment: how the solution will change if table 2 remains the same but we just have to match any single list at a time i.e if we pick only one list from table 1(lets remove any 2 lists from table 1) and try to find the missing values in table 2 from lst1 only.

Comment: I've appended an example how to emulate a lateral join on Oracle 10